# Class method loses private modifier after cast

Tags: c++

I need to set callback, but I dont want to make it global function, I dont need it public aswell, so I've made it private. Wondering, is it the right way to go.

```
class A // button object from window library. I wont change this class
{
public:
    typedef void (*fptr)();
    void set(fptr p)
    {
        p(); // here I call private static of B
    };
};
class B // my own class
{
private:
    static void prfn() {};
public:
    B()
    {
        A a;
        a.set(prfn);
    };
};
int main(){B b;}
```

Comment: Visibility is for the compiler. Here, in B, you are passing a function pointer. A real number representing a pointer to a function. So A calls a function from a physical address it received. Visibility will not be an issue.

Comment: so.. is it ok to set private static of window class as callback to say button?

Comment: @user1307996 Yes, you can do that if you want. its just a function pointer, so anyone that has compilation access to it can do whatever they want with it, including pass its address around.

Comment: Hmm, let me show you from the perspective of a set() method: I am a set method. I have just received number 0x2764391917 which is an address of a function that I need to call. I am already in the execution mode, not compilation, so there is no more talk about visibility but accessibility. If I can access this memory (not to cause segmentation fault) then surely I can. Let's try, and call the function at this address...   I hope it will help to see how it works. Visibility is a matter of the compiler, so the compiler can tell 'no you cannot access function of a name 'X'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine. It is no different from the following standard idiom:

```
class Foo
{
    int n;
public:
    int & the_int() { return n; }
};
```

It's perfectly fine to expose private members via public functions. (It may not be good design, but it's entirely legal.) You're doing the same thing by using a private member as a function argument for some other, unrelated purpose. Note that it is only your own `class B` that accesses a private member of `B`.

Answer (score 2):

That's perfectly fine, since you need access to the concrete (private) function only within class B. Class A won't care about access specifiers, the only contract is the function signature that must match the function pointer definition.

Answer (score 0):

First you use `set` that not introduced in `A` do you want to say `call`?
Second Why you should use another class to call some function (event `public` or `private`) of your own class?? You can simply say:

```
B() { prfn(); }
```

OK, if you want to implement a callback that you want to pass to another class and that function should not called directly by other users of your class, then you certainly doing right and your function should be private!

Comment: it was call, just changed for clarity.. undoed changes already

Comment: I have to set callback for button object (button from library) from inside my own window class(this class is mine).